# Compiling Linux kernel modules natively on ARM

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-toolchain

I am trying to install wifi and bluetooth drivers using this link, http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/WL18xx_System_Build_Scripts
on my ARM based board (microzed) running ubuntu 12.04.

As per step 2 of the link, where they have mentioned different parameters for cross compilation, I am confused on how to set these parameters because I am compiling natively on the ARM processor itself.

1.) TOOLCHAIN_PATH : What should this parameter be set to ? I am compiling natively on my processor itself. So, not sure what this should be set to.

2.) ROOTFS: What is this path generally ? How can i find this on my OS ?

3.) KERNEL_PATH: Is this the kernel header path ?
I have the folder, /usr/src/kernels/3.12.0-xillinux-1.3
Is this the kernel path that I should set to ?

And the parameters below:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
export ARCH=arm
```

can be left as it is or should they be changed to something else as I am compiling natively ?

Comment: `TOOLCHAIN_PATH=/bin;usr/bin` or something like that.  Try `which gcc`.  `ROOTFS=/` for building on the host==build==target or native.  I think that `KERNEL_PATH` is for headers and an install, but I am not 100% sure.  Read the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) for your kernel version.  Set `CROSS_COMPILE` to empty or `unset` it.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you don't need to cross-compile (but you will natively compile on your ARM machine):

- `TOOLCHAIN_PATH`: directory containing the gcc compiler (use  `which gcc` to discover)
- `ROOTFS=/`: directory containing the filesystem of the target (set to  `/` because you're not cross-compiling)
- `KERNEL_PATH`: directory containing an (already compiled) kernel for your board
- `CROSS_COMPILE`: leave it blank, since you are not cross-compiling
- `ARCH=arm`

By the way, if instead you need to cross-compile, then you have to set the variables as follows:

- `TOOLCHAIN_PATH`: directory containing the gcc *cross*-compiler
- `ROOTFS`: directory containing the filesystem of the target board
- `KERNEL_PATH`: directory containing an (already compiled) kernel for the target board
- `CROSS_COMPILE`: must be equal to the absolute path and the beginning of the name of the compiler stripped of the *gcc* name; for example if your compiler is `arm-linux-gcc` inside the directory `/my/path/` then you will set `CROSS_COMPILE=/my/path/arm-linux-`)
- `ARCH=arm`

Comment: Thanks. For cross compiling, should I copy the kernel headers (/lib/modules/3.12.0) from the ARM board into the PC and indicate that path in the KERNEL:PATH ? Also, what should I set ROOTFS to for cross compilation ? I am a bit confused with ROOTFS.

Comment: No:`KERNEL_PATH` points to a directory of a *full* kernel (not just headers) that must be *already compiled*. Unfortunately, that's needed by the Linux kernel module build system. Concerning  `ROOTFS`, no idea why this specific module needs it. I *suppose* that it is just where the binaries will be copied.